# How to push value from an array to another, one by one index

Tags: python, arrays, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```js
        parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        frame = parsed_html.find('div', {'id':'product-frame'})
        sizes = frame.findAll('div', {'class':'radio-options old-variant'}) # find all sizes
        sizing = []
        for s in sizes:
            sizing.append(s.label.text.replace('\t', '').replace('\n','').replace('\xa0','')) # format sizes
        
        sizes = [{
            
            'size': sizing,
            'in_stock': 'noStock' not in button['class']
            
        } for button in sizes]
```

Hello i have a problem pushing the 'sizing' array into 'size' array, it push all the value in the array instead of just push single value of an index making the output looks like this :

[image]

How can I push the size one by one index from sizing array into size array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that for every element of the `sizes` array, you are pushing the entire `sizing` list into it. instead what you need to do is use the index of the item and push the value at that index into it.
For example, this is one way of doing it:

```
sizes = [{
        
        'size': sizing[i],
        'in_stock': 'noStock' not in sizes[i]['class']
        
    } for i in range(len(sizes))]
```